# How to simulate a server outage with Spring web socket server?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

Im using a Spring web socket server based on `TextWebSocketHandler` for testing purposes. I want to simulate a network or server outage in my test. I can tell the server class to close all sessions, but that is not the same as pulling the network cable from the server, regarding the web socket protocol. The server class gets injected into my tests by Spring, but I see no way to simulate a server outage with it.

Is there a way to simulate a server outage without shifting the web socket server to another process and killing that process?